# Strange behavior of DiffEqUncertainty.jl and Quadrature.jl

Tags: julia

In Julia, I added two packages DiffEqUncertainty.jl and Quadrature.jl. However, I could not have both newest versions of them.

When I first added them by `] add DiffEqUncertainty, Quadrature`, by default, the version I got for DiffEqUncertainty is 1.2.0 and that for Quadrature.jl is 2.1.0. With these two packages, the command "expectation" cannot run.

Then, I run `] up`, but nothing changes. They still are of their same versions (not updated). I tried to forcedly update DiffEqUncertainty.jl package to its newest version by `] add DiffEqUncertainty@1.8.0`. However, while the version of DiffEqUncertainty.jl package is now 1.8.0, the version of Quadrature.jl package is *down* to 1.12.0. With these, the command "expectation" can run, **but only with** MonteCarlo() option. It cannot run with Koopman() option.

The situation is more strange that when I follow the link https://juliapackages.com/p/quadrature, and click to the button Github, it lead me to another package https://github.com/SciML/Integrals.jl.

Please help me to resolve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: The last issue just from juliapackages.com being out of date (as it often is) - Quadrature.jl got renamed to Integrals.jl about a month ago (with v3.0), and juliapackages hasn't caught up to the change yet.

Comment: Actually, the main issue may also root from the same name change issue - doing `add Quadrature` would fetch the old version before the name change, and that version likely depends on an old `DiffEqUncertainty` as well. Try `] add DiffEqUncertainty, Integrals` instead.

Comment: I removed DiffEqUncertainty and Quadrature packages by ```] rm DiffEqUncertainty, Quarature```, and then I followed your comment by ```] add DiffEqUncertainty, Integrals```. However, the version of DiffEqUncertainty package is still 1.2.0.

Comment: Ok, two separate issues here: 1. something else in your environment must be causing the `DiffEqUncertainty` version issue because doing `] add DiffEqUncertainty, Integrals` in a new, otherwise empty environment installs version 1.8.0 for me. But perhaps more importantly:

Comment: 2. `DiffEqUncertainty` declares its dependency as `Quadrature` major version 1, which must be why `Quadrature` goes down to 1.12.0 when you add `DiffEqUncertainty@1.8.0`. Unfortunately, this version of `Quadrature` seems incompatible with the code from the current `DiffEqBase`, so precompilation fails for this combination (I assume you see a precompile failure as well). I think this is in the realm of needing a Github issue at this point, so I'd suggest opening one on the DiffEqUncertainty repo and asking if the Quadrature.jl/Integrals.jl dependency version spec needs to be upgraded.

Comment: As @SundarR already mentioned that Quadrature.jl got renamed to Integrals.jl, so I guess that the strange behavior above can be resolved by redeclaring the dependency of ```DiffEqUncertainty.jl``` on ```Integrals.jl```, **not on Quadrature.jl anymore**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DiffEqUncertainty just needs an update to its own versioning. A major update to the package is coming with https://github.com/SciML/DiffEqUncertainty.jl/pull/55 so it just hasn't been updated in awhile.